# Considering a function f x = let f x = x+1 in f ( f x)

Tags: haskell

I'm studying for a syntax exam in Haskell and would love to receive some help of why this equals to 2:

" Consider the function:
f x = let f x = x+1 in f (f x)
What is the value of let x=0 in f x ? "

The answer to this is 2.

But "let f x = x+1" means that f (x+1). And then if we let x = 0 wouldn't that leave f(1)?

Thank you for reading

Comment: "The answer to this is 2." Does that mean you've tried running it? What else did you try?

Comment: Isn't your code the same as `f x  = let g y = y+1 in g(g x)`?

Comment: It's just what the answer sheet says. I also did try to try running it and received 2 when writing f(0)

Comment: This is a "classic" exercise that is testing your understanding of variable scope: there are two definitions for `f` and `x`, with nested scopes, and these should not be confused. As David suggests above, to understand this it's easier if you start by renaming the innermost definitions, preventing the confusion in the first place. Other common variants include `(\x -> (\x -> x)) 1 2` and `let x = 1 in let x = 2 in x+x`.

Answer (score 8):

There are two different functions being used. In the original function, there is no recursion; all references to `f` refer to the function defined by the `let` expression, not the function being defined. There are also two different scopes both containing a variable named `x`. It's clearer if you rename the inner function and its argument:

```
f x = let f' x' = x' + 1 in f' (f' x)
```

Now the other expression is easier to evaluate using equational reasoning:

```
let x = 0 in f x == f 0
                 == let f' x' = x' + 1 in f' (f' 0)
                 == (f' 0) + 1
                 == (0 + 1) + 1
                 == 1 + 1
                 == 2
```